# How much do the projectors project?

Tags: doctor-who, virtual-worlds

In “Extremis,” it seems as if the alien projectors are intended to

> holographically simulate possibly all of planet Earth.

However, there are only “portals” to a handful of places in the projector room, among which are the Vatican, the White House, the Pentagon, CERN, and so forth.

**So if the projectors project the whole Earth, why do they only seem to be projecting certain locations?**

This would tend to suggest that the aliens are only simulating important places, which would make sense: they want to model the places that would pose a threat to them when they really attack. While the nature of Earth society as a highly interacting system means that this would be impossible in reality (how can you simulate people walking into the White House if you don’t know where they should be walking *from*?) we can probably attribute this to [alien technology.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AWizardDidIt)

**But if the projectors only project certain places**, how do we explain Bill, Nardole, and the Doctor being part of the simulation?

**How much of the Earth do the projectors simulate?**

Comment: As Nardole said, they projected everything. The whole Earth. Possibly the "portals" were just some kind of bookmarks; shortcuts for quick access to key places.

Comment: Why are Bill, Nardole & the Doctor's being part of the simulation need explaining?

Comment: @KyleKanos - They don't, precisely. That would only need to be explained if the machines were somehow only simulating the power centers of the world.

Comment: apparently they project too much to expend any energy on producing a decent set of random numbers : p